# Separate git branches with different .gitignores for production and development

Tags: git

What i'm trying to achieve is to have 1 repository on bitbucket, with 2 separate branches, 1 for development and 1 for production.

Lets say I have a repository which has the following files

```
public_html
   - node_modules
   - package.json
   - scss
   - mynotes.txt
   - style.css
```

I need to be able to push all of these files (except the node modules) up to bitbucket so other developers can work on the repo.

I also need to be able to have a separate `.gitignore` which ignores all files that are not needed for production.

So lets say I have the full development on my local machine which `.gitignore` looks like this

```
node_modules
mynotes.txt
```

And a separate production branch which `.gitignore` looks like this

```
node_modules
mynotes.txt
sass
package.json
```

I then start editing the sass files, which generate a new `style.css` file and push all of my changes up to the repo.

I then want to ssh into my server, and do a git pull on the production version, but the production version only pulls the `style.css` file thats been changed, not any of the other files.

Basically what i'm trying to achieve is both production and development being fed off 1 repository. But being able to pull down different files based on different `.gitignore`s.

Sorry if this sounds confusing, its quite hard to explain!

Comment: Are you pushing `node_modules` to your version control?

Comment: No, i never want the node_modules folder to go up

Answer (score 1):

At plain sight, it can't be done. You can't just tell git "hey.... Pull from that other branch.... But only this and that file, not the others". If you want to try something like that you might have to use a third branch where you keep changes for those file so that you can easily pull from it to production without having changes in the flies you do 't want to carry into production.